# intel integrated graphics for display and nvidia GPU solely for machine learning: ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, intel, cuda

are there any ways to use intel integrated graphics for display and nvidia GPU solely for machine learning (CUDA).

System info:
desktop
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Processor: intel i9-13900K
GPU: nvidia RTX3090

there are a few old posts discussing this. however, none have an answer and those were for older versions.

[related post 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298821/using-intel-integrated-graphics-for-display-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-11-1-on-ubun).

[related post 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115767/how-to-use-2-displays-with-integrated-graphics-and-nvidia-for-cuda).

Kindly advise